# What is a Building Block Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

Hopefully, after the considerable amount of these types of puzzles on this website, you would know the drill :0

Still, if you want you can review the rules:

- Find out what characteristic a Building Block Word™ has.
- In addition, don't forget to justify why I call it a "Building Block Word™".

The list:

| Building Block Words™ | Not Building Block Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| PROTEST | RALLY |
| ILEUM | JEJUNUM |
| PHENOMENON | CIRCUMSTANCE |
| LEUKEMIA | MELANOMA |
| ALARMED | TERRIFIED |
| METRONOME | POLYRHYTHM |
| THRESHOLD | ACTIVATION |
| ASPIRATE | LABIALIZE |
| HISTORY | PREHISTORY |
| ARGUMENT | REBUTTAL |
| GLUE | TAPE |
| VALOR | BRAVERY |
| SERVICE | MEMBERSHIP |

The CSV version:

```
Building Block Words™,Not Building Block Words™
PROTEST, RALLY
ILEUM, JEJUNUM
PHENOMENON, CIRCUMSTANCE
LEUKEMIA, MELANOMA
ALARMED, TERRIFIED
METRONOME, POLYRHYTHM
THRESHOLD, ACTIVATION
ASPIRATE, LABIALIZE
HISTORY, PREHISTORY
ARGUMENT, REBUTTAL
GLUE, TAPE
VALOR, BRAVERY
SERVICE, MEMBERSHIP
```

Hint 1:

> Glycogen and cyst are Building Block Words™.

Comment: (And yes, I have taken the Puzzling SE tour. Thanks for the invitations :D )

Comment: Welcome, and nice first puzzle :)  For future reference, I provide and maintain a template for these types of puzzles that others are welcome to use. See e.g. [What is a Useful Word™?](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/83981) - you can click edit, copy the markup, and paste it into your own question as a starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building Block Words™ are words ...

> whose first three letters are an abbreviation for an  [amino acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid), the building blocks of life.

Specifically:

> Ala Alanine
>     Arg Arginine
>     Asn Asparagine
>     Asp Aspartic acid
>     Cys Cysteine
>     Gln Glutamine
>     Glu Glutamic acid
>     Gly Glycine
>     His Histidine
>     Ile Isoleucine
>     Leu Leucine
>     Lys Lysine
>     Met Methionine
>     Phe Phenylalanine
>     Pro Proline
>     Pyl Pyrrolysine
>     Ser Serine
>     Sec Selenocysteine
>     Thr Threonine
>     Trp Tryptophan
>     Tyr Tyrosine
>     Val Valine